# How to copy an area and paste into visible (filtered region)

Tags: excel, vba

I was thinking that this line would work, but instead I am getting an object error:

```
TemporaryBucketWorksheet.Range("$A$1:$AK$" & RowCountTotal).Copy MasterListMasterList.Range("$A$1:$AK$" & RowCountTotal).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Does anyone know why is that? I thought this would be a simple solution to pasting into visible cells but I guess this is not the case. How would I do it?

Comment: If you could explain why you would do this? Also, do those ranges have the same number of rows? Is it expected that one of them always has fewer rows? Please do clarify.

Comment: i want to copy one into the other (other being a filtered range); the range have the same number of rows yes

Comment: The ranges can have the same number of rows only if all cells are visible in the master worksheet. So the question is what will you do with the remainder of the rows in temporary sheet?

Comment: after pasting it over, I am going to delete the temporary sheet. I tried sth like this:
```
TemporaryBucketWorksheet.Range("$A$1:$AK$" & RowCountTotal).Copy
    MasterList.Range("$A$1:$AK$" & RowCountTotal).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```
getting method of range class failed now

Answer (score 0):

### Copy into Visible Range

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub copyToMulti()
    
    Const RowCountTotal As Long = 11
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = TemporaryBucketWorksheet.Range("$A$1:$AK$1")
    
    Dim drg As Range
    Set drg = MasterListMasterList.Range("$A$1:$AK$" & RowCountTotal) _
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    Dim arg As Range
    For Each arg In drg.Areas
        arg.Value = srg.Resize(arg.Rows.Count).Value
        Set srg = srg.Offset(arg.Rows.Count)
    Next arg
    
End Sub
```